# Retrieving nested json information from a postgresql table - no current index

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'd like to retrieve nested json information from a `jsonb` field (`sub_table`) in a postgresql table (`prices`).

I'm able to retrieve the json using the command:

```sql
with jsontable as (
    SELECT "sub_table"
    FROM "prices"
    WHERE "Scenario" = 'A' AND "data_type" = 'new'
    )
SELECT * from jsontable
```

This returns a `json` table like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "Name": "CompX",
        "Price": 10,
        "index": 1,
        "Date": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "1": {
        "Name": "CompY",
        "Price": 20,
        "index": 1,
        "Date": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "CompX",
        "Price": 19,
        "index": 2,
        "Date": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

I want to return all data relating to `Name = "CompX"` but can't get the query to work.

I've tried to follow the [examples here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html), but can't work it out. Do I need to reindex in some way?

Comment: What version of postgres are you using? Postgres 12 introduced a powerful JSON query tool that would be very useful in this case - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH

Comment: I'm using `(12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return extracted JSONB data row-wisely by using `jsonb_each` function with filtering out by `(j.value -> 'Name')::text = '"CompX"'` condition :

```
SELECT j.value
  FROM prices p
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(sub_table) AS j(e)
 WHERE (j.value -> 'Name')::text = '"CompX"'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa34d28334ca4ce6310f9b0630878c9e)</kbd>